# Putting the object of userdefined type on clipboard and retriving it

Tags: c#, clipboard

I am having a class Student. I want to store the object of class Student 'objStu' on the clipboard.

```
Class Student
{
    string stuID;
    string Name;
    string email;
}
```

In the main method I wrote a code:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(objStu,false);
```

When I tried to retrive the object as below:

```
Student anotherStu = Clipboard.GetDataObject() as Student;
```

It is returning null. Please guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: Refer this-[Saving and obtaining custom objects to/from Windows Clipboard](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8102/Saving-and-obtaining-custom-objects-to-from-Window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make Student class as `Serializable`

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    public string stuID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public void CopyToClipboard()
    {

        DataFormats.Format format =
             DataFormats.GetFormat(typeof(Student).FullName);
        //now copy to clipboard
        IDataObject dataObj = new DataObject();
        dataObj.SetData(format.Name, false, this);
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, false);

    }
```

then you try as:

```
Student objStu = new Student();
objStu.Name = "test";
objStu.CopyToClipboard();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(objStu, false);
Student anotherStu = GetFromClipboard();
```

below is the GetFromClipboard method

```
protected static Student GetFromClipboard()
{
    Student student = null;
    IDataObject dataObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    string format = typeof(Student).FullName;

    if (dataObj.GetDataPresent(format))
    {
        student = dataObj.GetData(format) as Student;
    }
    return student;
}
```

Check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8102/Saving-and-obtaining-custom-objects-to-from-Window) for more information